# Publisher Subscriber - Subscribe to Selected Messages in a Topic

Tags: events, messaging, solace

I am looking at designing a Publisher/Subscriber Event Broker/Messaging System to communicate between Microservices.
Suppose I have 50 PODS subscribed to a topic called "Cars". Few of the PODS are only interested in receiving messages for "Ford", while some others are interested in messages for "Toyota, Honda" (both of them).

Can Topic be made dynamic like Cars/{CarName}, so when the publisher send data for "Ford" to the channel, its sent to only PODS subscribed for "Ford"?

I was particularly looking at Solace PubSub+. Are there other products that can achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's actually a best practice in Solace to use hierarchical topics with information in the topics that you want to filter on.

Topic Best Practices: https://docs.solace.com/Messaging/Topic-Architecture-Best-Practices.htm?Highlight=topic%20best%20practices

Quick YouTube Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP1nNlgERQI&ab_channel=Solace